# Cannot get ratings from Recommenderlab for sparse binary ratings matrix

Tags: r, matrix, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

The data used is a ratings matrix generated from simple 0-1 yes/no click data based on whether or not a user visited a section of a website. This is implicit voting since if a user is interested in a section he will click it and thus rate it as a "1" and if not rate it as a "0". The ratings matrix thus has 32711 users in the rows and 285 site sections in the columns, after removing 9 that had no user visits.

I run:

```
library("recommenderlab")
ratingmatrix <- read.csv("ratingmatrix3.txt",",",header=TRUE, row.names=1 )
ratingmatrix <- as.matrix(ratingmatrix)
ratingmatrix <- as(ratingmatrix, "realRatingMatrix")

Rec1 <- Recommender(ratingmatrix[1:1000], method="POPULAR")
pred1 <- predict(Rec1, ratingmatrix[1001:1011], type="ratings")
as(pred1,"matrix")[,1:10]
```

I only get a prediction matrix with NAs implying that no predictions were made. It is the same with any other method; above POPULAR is used.

Does recommenderlab only deal with denser matrices? Does anyone have any ideas on how to deal with matrices with 0-1 votes, and no NAs? Thanks.

Output:

```
      South.Africa Site.Builder.Workshop Netherlands..Holland. Europe
11001           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11002           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11003           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11004           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11005           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11006           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11007           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11008           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11009           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11010           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
11011           NA                    NA                    NA     NA
      Microsoft.Solution.Providers Microsoft.Financial.Forum For.Developers.Only.News
11001                           NA                        NA                       NA
11002                           NA                        NA                       NA
11003                           NA                        NA                       NA
11004                           NA                        NA                       NA
11005                           NA                        NA                       NA
11006                           NA                        NA                       NA
11007                           NA                        NA                       NA
11008                           NA                        NA                       NA
11009                           NA                        NA                       NA
11010                           NA                        NA                       NA
11011                           NA                        NA                       NA
      Visual.Fox.Pro.Support Educational.Services...Programs Chile
11001                     NA                              NA    NA
11002                     NA                              NA    NA
11003                     NA                              NA    NA
11004                     NA                              NA    NA
11005                     NA                              NA    NA
11006                     NA                              NA    NA
11007                     NA                              NA    NA
11008                     NA                              NA    NA
11009                     NA                              NA    NA
11010                     NA                              NA    NA
11011                     NA                              NA    NA
```

Comment: If you got binary data, why don't you use a `binaryRatingMatrix` instead of a `realRatingMatrix`?

Comment: Your input data is probably not in the right format, but it is hard to say without the data.